# how do i activate the other loop (if /else if)

Tags: c#

Im having problem with a program that takes farenheight translates it to celsius and tells you if the temperature is too low or too high.
Right now the to low part works but for some reason the loop doesn't work when it's to high.

```
using System;

namespace Bastun2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");

            double temperatureF = double.NaN;

                if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperatureF) && temperatureF < 163.4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF}°F is to low, enter a higher temperature");
                }

                //double temperatureC = (temperatureF  - 32) * 5 / 9;

                //Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF}°F, {temperatureC}°C");



            else if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperatureF) && temperatureF > 170.6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF} °F is to high, enter a lower temperature");
            }

            double temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;

            Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF}°F, {temperatureC}°C");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your else if statement you are reading from the console again. You should only read the value once, save it inside a variable and check against that variable.

Comment: Actually I see that you speak abou a loop, bu I can't see any loop. Do you miss to upload some of your code maybe? Because in your case when you insert a 'higher temperature' It just enter in the else-if and quit. I'm also sure that also if you insert two times a lower temperature it won't work

Comment: I can suggest to add a do-while loop with the following condition (temperatureF <163.4 && temperatureF > 170.6).

Comment: Where would i put the do-while loop? Before the if statements?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any loop here.

Store the result of `Console.ReadLine()` in a variable like so :

```cs
double temperatureF = double.NaN;
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperatureF);
```

And replace where you used `Console.ReadLine()` previously by `temperatureF`.

Comment: The `double.TryParse` also needs to happen just once

Answer (score 0):

You are reading two times from the console. After your first check failed, the user has to input another value so the second check can happen.

You should only read the input once and store it in a varibale. Then you can check on that variable.

You could also use a loop, so the user does not have too restart the program until he enters a valid input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double temperatureF = double.NaN;
    string input = string.Empty;
    bool inputIsOkay = false;


    while(!inputIsOkay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");

        input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!double.TryParse(input, out temperatureF)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"'{input}' is not a valid input...");
        }
        else if (temperatureF < 163.4)
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF}°F is to low, enter a higher temperature");
        }
        else if (temperatureF > 170.6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF} °F is to high, enter a lower temperature");
        }
        else
        {
            inputIsOkay = true;
        }
    }

    double temperatureC = (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;

    Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureF}°F, {temperatureC}°C");
        
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```